# Can you use 1 large SSD device for booting and data (2 partitions) on Pi4?

Tags: boot, hardware, pi-4

I want to use one partition for booting (RASPIOS) and one for the data files. The reasons I have are: 1- cost per GB on SSD devices is less and 2-separate devices causes more heat along with increased load on the power supply. Any booting problems using 2 partitions on one SSD?

Comment: What do you mean by 'capture 2 partitions'?

Comment: Have one for RASPIOS and one for the data files. I was unable to partition my SD card to do this and wondered if I would have the same problem.

Comment: What have you tried, how has it failed? Are you using a tool like gparted to help you do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> I want to use one partition for booting (RASPIOS) and one for the data files.

The Raspberry Pi OS uses two partitions by default: one for booting, formatted as **fat32**, and one as root filesystem, formatted as **ext4**, containing all modules and programs to run the operating system. With a default Raspberry Pi OS the second partition is expanded to its maximum size on first bootup of the image. If using a big SSD device there is a lot of free space available on the second partition you want to store data files. Just create a directory:

```
rpi ~$ sudo mkdir /data
```

and use this directory as storage for the data files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can partition an SSD.

If you're using Windows you can use this guide to partition your SSD: https://www.wikihow.com/Partition-a-Drive-on-Windows

You can then use a tool like Etcher to flash the .iso to the partition you created for your OS.

You can use the other partition for normal storage.

Comment: Thanks aklingam but let me apologize for the stupid way I asked my question. The real issue is when you are using the new booting process (using a device on Pi's USB), how does Pi4 know to go to the partition that has RASPIOS? I thought that Pi's boot level is at the device and not a particular entity on that devise. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Have you tested that method? AFAIK Etcher writes to a disk, not a partition, meaning you will lose all existing partition info. There are other methods that *will* work

Comment: Thanks, @Dirk you'd have to create the partition after you flash the .iso

Comment: @tomd Thanks a lot for the clarification I'm not familiar with how the boot order works on the Pi. Here is some documentation that might help you in case nobody else answers: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/bootflow.md